# Can't make the Gtranslate language work inside drop down list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I want to use Gtranslate.io languages on my website. I am using flags right now without any drop-down and everything works fine. But now I want to put the flags inside a drop-down list. I want the default to be English whenever someone gets into my website but can choose a language from the list and that will be active. Please check both the code pens about the code:

- [Code which works on my website.](https://codepen.io/zakero/pen/VwZyPVP)
- [Code which doesn't work on my website:](https://codepen.io/zakero/pen/VwZyPRp)

```
<div class="languages">
                    <a href="#" onclick="doGTranslate('en|en');return false;" title="English" class="gflag nturl" style="background-position:-0px -0px;"><img src="images/english.png" height="16" width="16" alt="English" /></a>
                    <a href="#" onclick="doGTranslate('en|fr');return false;" title="French" class="gflag nturl" style="background-position:-200px -100px;"><img src="images/france.png" height="16" width="16" alt="French" /></a>
                    <a href="#" onclick="doGTranslate('en|de');return false;" title="German" class="gflag nturl" style="background-position:-300px -100px;"><img src="images/germany.png" height="16" width="16" alt="German" /></a>
                    <a href="#" onclick="doGTranslate('en|it');return false;" title="Italian" class="gflag nturl" style="background-position:-600px -100px;"><img src="images/italy.png" height="16" width="16" alt="Italian" /></a>
<div id="google_translate_element2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Neither codepen works. You did not include the `doGTranslate` function or any of the libraries needed to support that. Please post the minimal code to your question. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Hi. Sorry about that. Please check the code pens now. The first one works but the second one doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second codepen isn't working because `div[id="google_translate_element2"]` is not present in the document.

Once you place it on the page and change the select value, it can work. I also would recommend removing the `<a>` nodes from within the options and instead using the `onchange` attribute on the `<select>`

Be cautious, changes to Google's logo and branding output may breach their [Attribution Requirements](https://cloud.google.com/translate/attribution#attribution-and-logos)

See [my fork](https://codepen.io/floppytop-the-sasster/pen/zYOpZdK) of your code